# - in xml tag simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have tags like this in my xml

```
<sub-up ...>...</sub-up>
```

and when I do this

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($decodeData);

foreach ($xmlData->sub-up->result as $res) {
    print_r($res);
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"

But when I replace this tag to `subup` everything works well. What can I do? I can't replace all `-` or characters like this

Is there any solution?

Comment: `foreach ($xmlData->{'sub-up'}->result as $res) {`

Comment: wow. thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
foreach ($xmlData->{'sub-up'}->result as $res) {
```

In your code `-` is evaluating as minus.

Comment: works thanks a lot for fast answer